# Flutter How to call PUT GET API for Sensor

Tags: java, flutter, dart, sensors, movesense

I have Sensors from them i want to Display the Data of the Sensor(Accelorometer, Gyroscope, Magnetometer) and log that recorded data.

From the Documentation I see following PUT and GET Requests that I need to perform. I also have a [Example](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib/src/master/android/samples/DataLoggerSample/app/src/main/java/com/movesense/samples/dataloggersample/DataLoggerActivity.java) but that is written in java but I'm not familiar with Java.

PUT /Mem/DataLogger/Config that lists paths that you want to log.
In my case they would be /Meas/IMU9/104 and /Meas/Temp.

```
PUT /Mem/DataLogger/State to 3 (=LOGGING)
PUT /Mem/DataLogger/State to 2 (=READY)
GET "suunto:/MDS/Logbook/{serial}/Entries" on mobile to have a list of entries on the sensors datamemory. The one with biggest LogID is the one you just recorded
GET "suunto:/MDS/Logbook/{serial}/byId/{LogId}/Data" on mobile to get the recording as JSON.
```

For all that i need the http Plugin. I started with creating Final String's for the Entries.

My current Code looks like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:mdsflutter/Mds.dart';

class DataLoggerActivity extends StatefulWidget {
  final String URI_MDS_LOGBOOK_ENTRIES = "suunto://MDS/Logbook/{0}/Entries";
  final String URI_MDS_LOGBOOK_DATA = "suunto://MDS/Logbook/{0}/ById/{1}/Data";

  final String URI_LOGBOOK_ENTRIES = "suunto://{0}/Mem/Logbook/Entries";
  final String URI_DATALOGGER_STATE = "suunto://{0}/Mem/DataLogger/State";
  final String URI_DATALOGGER_CONFIG = "suunto://{0}/Mem/DataLogger/Config";


  @override
  _DataLoggerActivityState createState() => _DataLoggerActivityState();
}

class _DataLoggerActivityState extends State<DataLoggerActivity> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the GET & PUT are not HTTP calls (so no HTTP plugin), but calls in MDS library. Please check the latest [mdsflutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/mdsflutter) and the example within.

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*